# Possible Combinatorial Identity and Ordered Partitions?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions, permutations

I want to consider the following expansion.

$$\bigg(\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg)^{2g-2} = \sum_{h=0}^{\infty} \varphi^{(g)}_{h} x^{2h}$$

for $g \geq 2$, where the coefficients are given explixitly by,

$$\varphi^{(g)}_{h} = \frac{(-1)^{h}}{2^{2g+2h-3}} \sum_{k=0}^{g-2} (-1)^{k}\binom{2g-2}{k}\frac{(2k-2g+2)^{2h+2g-2}}{(2h+2g-2)!}.$$

Now, I want to consider **ordered** partitions of an integer $n$.  Such an ordered partition $\pi \in \mathcal{P}_{n}$ can be written as an $n$-tuple

$$\pi = \{ \pi_{1}, \pi_{2}, \ldots, \pi_{n} \}.$$

I think this is probably familiar, but for an example of how this works, the following ordered partition of $n=4$

$$\{ \cdot \,\,|\,\, \cdot \,\,\,\, \cdot \,\,\,\, \cdot \}$$

I would write as $\{1,3,0,0\}$ because the second and third barriers are not present.  Now, an object that appeared naturally in something I was studying, is the following sum over ordered partitions of products of the coefficients $\varphi$ above:

$$\sum_{\pi \in \mathcal{P}_{n}} (-1)^{\epsilon_{\pi}}\varphi^{(g-1)}_{\pi_{1}} \varphi^{(g-2)}_{\pi_{2}} \cdots \varphi_{\pi_{n}}^{(g-n)}$$

for $g \geq2$ and $1 \leq n \leq g-2$, where $\epsilon_{\pi}$ is the number of non-zero entries in the tuple.  **So my question simply is, can anyone imagine an identity which simplifies this above sum, or let's me write it in terms of more well-known objects?**  In particular, are they related to Bernoulli numbers by chance?  This might just be some random, unattractive quantity, but my instincts tell me it might be nice.

I wish I could provide the context in which this arises but it would require too much preamble.  Long story short, these sums (multiplied by some Bernoulli numbers) are the coefficients of a sum of Eisenstein Series which amazingly has integral coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i,h} x^h$ then $$f_1(x) f_2(x) \cdots f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\pi \in C_{n,m}} a_{1,\pi_1} a_{2, \pi_2} \cdots a_{m, \pi_m}x^n$$ where the sum is taken over the set $C_{n,m}$ of ordered partitions of $n$ with $m$ parts, allowing zeroes (also called *weak compositions*).  In your case you can fix $g$ and let $$f_i(x) = \left(\frac{  \sin{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}}  }{  \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}}\right)^{2(g-i)-2} = \sum_{h=0}^{\infty} \varphi^{(g-i)}_{h} x^{h}.$$  Then your sum is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f_1(x) f_2(x) \ldots f_n(x)$.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you!  If I'm parsing your syntax correctly in that exponent, you could cancel the 2's and just have $g-i$.  Then couldn't you say that the product of all $n$ functions equals the term in the parenthesis raised to the power of $ng-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: Oops, I meant that exponent to be the same as yours, $2(g-i) -2$.  I will edit.

Comment: But yes, you can simplify by adding the exponents

Comment: Great, thanks.  There's no obstruction to replacing your $\sqrt{x}$ by $x$ as long as it's done on both sides, right?

Comment: Sure, if you want to get rid of the square root you could take the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ of $f_1(x^2) \cdots f_n(x^2)$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot for this.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I realized that I very stupidly forgot a factor of $(-1)^{\epsilon_{\pi}}$ in my sum over ordered partitions (I've edited above).  This gives a minus sign to all terms with a odd number of non-zero coefficients.  Sadly, I've been thinking that this destroys the connection to weak compositions as you explained, right? :(

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco No, I think you can fix it (if I understand your terminology here.)  You just need to change the sign of all the $\varphi$'s except for the constant term.  If $f_i(x) = 1 + \varphi_1^{g-i} x + \varphi_2^{g-i}x^2 + \cdots$ you can use  $2 - f_i(x) = 1  - \varphi_1^{g-i} x - \varphi_2^{g-i}x^2 - \cdots$ instead.